# How to find the text value in dropdown list using Request.Form

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How to find text value from requested formm?

```
dr["Boxno"] = Request.Form["Ddlbox_1"];
dr["Boxno"] = Request.Form["Ddlbox_" + i];
```

Answer (score 0):

In server side you can access only `name` and `value` attribute of input element not text within it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using web forms there is no need to access Request.Form to retrieve the value of the dropdowns.

If you have multiple dropdowns and you want to iterate through the dropdowns you can use `FindControl` to find each dropdown by it's name (e.g. `FindControl("Ddlbox_" + i)`)

`FindControl` will return an object of type `object`which you can then cast to `DropDownList`in order to access the selected value via `ddl.SelectedValue` or the text via `ddl.SelectedItem.Text` (ddl is the variable of your dropdown list).

Please note: if the dropdowns are created for example in a repeater control, you'll need to iterate each item of the repeater and apply the `FindControl` method to each row.